# How to avoid Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) on android

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm using HttpURLConnection to get a web service, the server is in the same network but the responce can be delayed to 60000ms (bcs of some complicated causes i must set it to 60000ms), when i hit listview item to call the webservice and waiting for the responce and loose the wifi signal and continue clicking the list my app crash with no exception the error is `A/libc(9052): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) on android at 0x000001e5 (code=0), thread 9052` 
more clear: `webservice call+ wifi lost+ clicks = Fatal signal 6 code=0`
I'm trying to avoid this by:

1. Blocking the UI or showing please wait but my please waite don't appear bcause there continious cliks
2. Avoid UI cliks
   but no way!! please help, any propo and discussions are apreciated..

   ```
   public static boolean stopUserInteractions=false;
   private class GetXmlAndStopUI extends AsyncTask<List, Void, String> {

   private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

   @Override   
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
       this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
       this.dialog.show();

   }
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(final List... items) {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               webserviceCall(items[0]);
           }
       }); 

   return "MSG";
   }
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   stopUserInteractions=false;
           if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {  
                   this.dialog.dismiss();  
           }
   }
   }



   @Override
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
           if (stopUserInteractions) {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "STOP!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
           } else {
           return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: You simply may not block the UI for more than a fraction of a second.  And doing network operations on the UI thread is basically prohibited in the last few versions of Android regardless of how long they take.  Move your network operations off the UI thread.  Informing the user that you are busy, and responding to their actions by consuming them is a different matter.

Comment: That mean i must remove runOnUiThread and run the HttpUrlConnection in a thread, but i don't have any problem when my connection is good, the problem occurs when the wireless signal is lost and my request is already sent!!

Comment: The reason why recent android versions proactively crash if you attempt *any* network operation on the UI thread (is that as you are discovering with your tests against an older or de-strictified version) network operations can incur delays, and that leads to a bad user experience.  Fix it correctly, by switching to a fully event-based paradigm where *completing* the network operation is just another event which triggers a change of the UI state, and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStratton for your support, im still blocked :s, that's exactly what im trying to do by my boolean 'stopUserInteractions' to stop all UI events after the first click and wait till the response return, so i'm using the ProgressDialog for the same reason, but the problem occurs when clicking lots of clicks one after one in short time+"lost wifi network", UI successive clicks prevent showing my progress and so my toasts, after 5sec of "successive clicks" the app crash :S.

Comment: Don't tell the user to stop (especially more than once) just ignore them, or put up another dialog or view with no controls (they can still back or home if frustrated).

Comment: Using runOnUiThread with your webservice operation is exactly backwards.